# IOS - Facebook score and timeline

Tags: facebook, post, leaderboard

I'am trying to make facebook leader board for my app.. but i don't under stand that

WHY NOT PUBLISH NEWSFEED or Any other info to my facebook test user pages?

my source code have any problem? =(

[Sandbox mode/3test user tried/there is no error]
Write permission is OK.

Fetching current score is OK.

Score post returns no error and "FACEBOOK_NON_JSON_RESULT" = true;

[self FBRequestWritePermissions];

```
NSMutableDictionary* params =   [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                 [FBSession activeSession].accessTokenData.accessToken,@"access_token",                                     [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", nScore], @"score",
                                 nil];
NSLog(@"Access Token : %@",[FBSession activeSession].accessTokenData.accessToken);

NSLog(@"Fetching current score");

// Get the score, and only send the updated score if it's highter
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%llu/scores", _myData.idName] parameters:params HTTPMethod:@"GET" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {

    if (result && !error) {

        int nCurrentScore = 0;

        if ([[result objectForKey:@"data"]count] > 0) {
            nCurrentScore = [[[[result objectForKey:@"data"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"score"] intValue];
        }


        NSLog(@"Current score is %d", nCurrentScore);

        if (nScore > nCurrentScore) {

            NSLog(@"Posting new score of %d", nScore); 
            [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%llu/scores", _myData.idName]
                                         parameters:params
                                         HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                                  completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {

                NSLog(@"Score posted:%@ \n\n %@ \n\n%@",result,error,_isPublishable==YES?@"YES":@"NO");
            }];
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"Existing score is higher - not posting new score");
        }
    }

}];
```

Facebook tutorial saids..

"The process is simple. Each time a player achieves a score in the game, the game issues an HTTP POST request /USER_ID/scores with a user access_token. Assuming the user has granted the publish_actions permission, their score will post to the graph

From there, Facebook can automatically generate several interesting stories, including high score stories when the player reaches a new high score, and passing stories when the player overtakes a friend in the game."

But i don't understand why not post to the graph...?